# Can you add context to Django Haystack from urls.py?

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-haystack

I'd like to get the number of search results in the template but Django Haystack's SearchView only provides

```
context = {
'query': self.query,
'form': self.form,
'page': page,
'paginator': paginator,
'suggestion': None,
}
```

I noticed SearchView defines

```
def extra_context(self):
"""
Allows the addition of more context variables as needed.

Must return a dictionary.
"""
return {}
```

But is there a way to do that in urls.py because I'm happy with what I have there (don't have to do any work in views.py).

This is my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns += patterns('haystack.views',
    url(r'^search/', 
        login_required(lambda request: SearchView(
        searchqueryset=SearchQuerySet().filter(author=request.user).order_by('-pub_date'),
        form_class=SearchForm
    )(request)), name='haystack_search'),
)
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

In your template you *should* do `{{ searchqueryset.count }}` and then not need to clutter your `urls.py` further.